# App Crash in 4.0 in Splash screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi Friends my Application work in all API but when i run in 4.0 it crash ..have any Idea about this problem? any more information add in project for run in 4.0? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about giving more information? ;-)

Comment: more information in the sense " any Permission? or any minSdkVersion Changing or any extra specific infomation adding .."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super random guess:

You're doing a Network request on the main thread, doing so will cause an exception in 3.0 and later.

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to move the request onto another thread.
Since you're doing this on a splash screen, don't advance to the next part until the request is done, but put a progress indicator to show something is happening in the background.